# Executing chef recipe only after another recipe is finished

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have two recipes in different cookbooks. I need the first recipe to be completely finished before the second one starts execution, as it places some files that the second will need. I put the first one before the second in the run list, but it seems as if they get executed in parallel.

How can I trigger the second recipe's execution when the first is done? (Note that they are in different cookbooks.)

Comment: looks like this is an open issue with OpsCode (http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3376). Can you create a role and specify a setup recipe for each cookbook? That could force the cookbooks to load in a specific order, right?

Comment: That might work. Another temporary solution, and the one I'm using currently, is to force the second cookbook to depend on the first. I did not want to do this because it seems inelegant to add a dependency from the second cookbook to the first when for many of my deployments the first is not even necessary.

Comment: To force the dependency are you just saying something like `include_recipe otherckbk::recipe1` in your other cookbook?

Comment: Yes, and `depends "otherckbk"` in the metadata file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a snippet of the code. My guess is that you're making use of LWRP (possibly inbuilt) and they are all getting executed towards the end of the run. Does this sound familiar?

Code like:

```
cookbook_file node['.NET']['FilePath'] do
  source node['.NET']['FileName']
  action :create
end
```

could get converted to:

```
configFile = cookbook_file node['.NET']['FilePath'] do
  source node['.NET']['FileName']
  action :nothing
end
configFile.run_action(:create)
```

which means the execution is forced at that part of the code (ie when we are resolving the recipe)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'm not using LWRPs in these recipes, but there are other recipes in the runlist that do. Would those trigger this behaviour?

Comment: Could do. A lot of inbuilt.functions like cookbook_file and template exhibit this behaviour. How are you creating the files in the first recipe for consumption in the 2nd? Is the issue that the files aren't present when the 2nd recipe is running and hence it falls over?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the issue. The first recipe creates the files with `cookbook_file "/path/to/file.txt" do source "file.txt" end `

Comment: Try adding the run_action bit I have the answer and you should be good :)

Comment: If this sorted your problem could you accept the answer for other people? Thanks

Comment: Yup, will do as soon as I confirm this fixes the issue. Thanks!