# Adding recipes to Chef run_list and chef-client -o option

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have `node.run_list.add('recipe[ckbk::recipe_name]')` in a `ckbk::recipe`. When chef-client is run with -o option the `recipe_name` in `run_list.add` is not added to the runlist. Is this the expected behavior of using `chef-client -o`.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure modifying the node.run_list will NOT actually add the recipe to your runlist.  It will just add it to the attribute, but not cause the recipe to be executed.

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the behavior i.e the recipe is added to the attribute bit not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `run_list.add` ever affects the current run. That would require a full re-expansion of the run list and version solution. "Normally" that would just affect your next run, but `-o` automatically disables saving node data back to the server because you could end up with partial data.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. So in short the runlist can't be changed dynamically during chef-client run.

Comment: You can use `include_recipe` to dynamically decide which recipes are run, but you can't add or remove cookbooks during the run.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running chef client with `-o` option, you override runlist for only that run, so basically freezes runlist to your new one, and you're not able to change it.

```
-o RUN_LIST_ITEM, --override-runlist RUN_LIST_ITEM
Replace the current run list with the specified items. This option will not clear the list of cookbooks (and related files) that is cached on the node.
```

You can use `include_recipe` to include multiple (other) recipes yo your main recipe. It will not change runlist, but included recipe will be added as lower level dependency to your runlist.

Comment: Thanks @rastasheep. Since I need to run a recipe to be run as the last one in the run_list I was not able to go with `include_recipe`.

Comment: Since it's your cookbook, you can notify your resource to run at the end of the run. Here are a few examples https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifies-syntax https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#examples or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13140171/2760469

Comment: Thanks again. Since this is to execute a `recipe` at the end, wondering any techniques are there similar to that of `notifying` a `resource` .